Distinguishing between the landmarks (left hand and right hand)
I have been trying to distinguish between the landmark with the same number for the left-hand and right-hand in mediapipe and opencv. The problem is that we have 20 id numbers but for both hands we have 40 landmarks. Eventually I want to extract the coordinates of for example landmark#8 on the left-hand and right-hand separately. Here is the minimal work I have done so far to put markers with different colors (circles) on the landmarks with the same number on the the left and right hands but it did not work (They get the same color again):
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands(max_num_hands=2)
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

while True:    
    
success, img = cap.read()
img = cv2.flip(img, 1) 
time.sleep(0.1)
imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

results = hands.process(imgRGB)
    
if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
    
    for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:        
         
        for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                                    
            h,w,c = img.shape    
            cx, cy, cz = int(lm.x*w), int (lm.y*h) , int (lm.z*c)
            lbl = results.multi_handedness[0].classification[0].label
                           
            if lbl == 'Right':
                
                if id == 8:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy),8, (255,0,0), cv2.FILLED)
                    
            if lbl == 'Left':
                
                if id == 8 :
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy),8, (255,255,0), cv2.FILLED)

        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,\
            mpDraw.DrawingSpec(color=(121,0,255)),\
                mpDraw.DrawingSpec(color=(0,255,0)))
    
cv2.imshow("image", img)
c = cv2.waitKey(7) % 0x100
if c == 27:
    break

I was hoping there is a solution to fully distinguish between all 40 landmarks for both hands.

Which mediapipe version are you using? this seems like an outdated API...see https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker/python

I used the command "pip install mediapipe" for installation with python 3.12

Using the MP API described here, the proper way to distinguish between hand landmarks is to parse the Handedness field in the HandLandmarkerResult.
i.e.
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision

BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions
HandLandmarker = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarker
HandLandmarkerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerOptions
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

# Create a hand landmarker instance with the video mode:
options = HandLandmarkerOptions(
    base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path='/path/to/model.task'),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.VIDEO)  # this example is for offline video processing
my_detector = HandLandmarker.create_from_options(options)
# Use OpenCV’s VideoCapture to load the input video.
# Load the frame rate of the video using OpenCV’s CV_CAP_PROP_FPS
# You’ll need it to calculate the timestamp for each frame.
# Loop through each frame in the video using VideoCapture#read()
# Convert the frame received from OpenCV to a MediaPipe’s Image object.
mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=numpy_frame_from_opencv)
hand_landmarker_result = my_detector.detect_for_video(mp_image, frame_timestamp_ms)
right_landmarks = np.zeros((21, 2), dtype=np.float32)
left_landmarks = np.zeros((21, 2), dtype=np.float32)
for j in range(len(detection_result.hand_landmarks)):
    # Verify these belong to right hand (otherwise, left)
    handness = detection_result.handedness[j][0].display_name == "Right"
    landmarks = np.array(
        [
            [landmark.x, landmark.y]
            for landmark in detection_result.hand_landmarks[j]
        ]
    ).astype(np.float32)
    if handness:
        right_landmarks = landmarks
    else:
        left_landmarks = landmarks
    # further processing ...

